# Generifying javascript code for jQuery and knockout.js to be a reusable module

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to build a very specific module that integrates Twitter bootstrap (for the tabs), jQuery (for ease of development) and knockout.js for client-side view models. The idea is that I have one HTML page, which has 3 div's defined in it. Each div is a tab, with only one div visible at a particular time. When a div is displayed it should call a load method on a knockout.js viewmodel that is scoped to the tab and reload the data from the server.

I have written the following code (which works), however it is very specific to a particular tab in my application.

```
// only configure this once the DOM is ready for processing.
// this code snippet is very long winded and quite a hack, however it allows the content of a bootstrap.js
// tab to be reloaded when the tab is made visible. It does this by calling the LoadCategory() method on the
// knockout.js view model.
//
// it is also worth noting that the view model is bound using knockout to only descendents of the div that contains
// the tab contents. This is to ensure that we can have several knockout view models in one page without needing to
// worry about them interfering with each other.
$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialise the model...
    var todaysQuestionsModel = new ViewModel(categoryId);

    // if this tab is visible to begin with, load the view model.
    if ($('#todays-questions').hasClass('active')) {
        todaysQuestionsModel.LoadCategory();
    }

    // only apply these bindings to the elements that descend from the div that contains this tab.
    ko.applyBindings(todaysQuestionsModel, document.getElementById("#todays-questions"));

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
        if (e.target.hash == '#todays-questions') {
            todaysQuestionsModel.LoadCategory();
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to be able to wrap this up in a javascript module that I can reuse for different parts of my application, however I am at a loss as to how to generify this code. Ideally I would like to be able to just make a simple function call to configure all of this behaviour automatically.

I assume for the part where the todaysQuestionsModel.LoadCategory() call is made that this should be a callback function. I also assume there should be some way that I don't have to specify the id selector, but any attempt I have made so far doesn't seem to work.

Could someone help me out with this, I am quite out of my depth here :-).

Cheers,

Aidan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the event handling by knockout.
This is a modified sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/xVxKD/52/

```
   <div class="tabbable">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: tabs">
        <li data-bind="css: { active: $root.selected() === $data }">
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.doSomething, text: title"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" data-bind="foreach: tabs">
        <div class="tab-pane" data-bind="css: { active: $root.selected() === $data }">
          <p data-bind="text: content"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>​


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
function Tab(id, title, content) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.title = ko.observable(title);
    this.content = ko.observable(content);
}

var viewModel = {
    tabs: ko.observableArray([
        new Tab(1, "one", "one content"), 
        new Tab(2, "two", "two content"), 
        new Tab(3, "three", "three content")
    ]),
    selected: ko.observable(),        

    doSomething: function($data, $event){
        //alert(' = '+$event.target.hash)
        $data.content($data.content() + '\n Do i need to fetch new content for you?')
        viewModel.selected($data);
    }

};

//select second tab by default
viewModel.selected(viewModel.tabs()[1]);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});//]]>  

</script>
```